# How to add custom View to list adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which is being created by custom listadapter.In this list view i want one text and one view for every item of listview.I am getting able to add text.My view is a view which is a custom view.it is not adding.I do not know why? Anyone wanna help?

```
private class ItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    String[] items;
    Context context;
    public ItemsAdapter(Context context,String[] items){
        this.items=items;
        this.context=context;
    }

    public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup Parent){
        TextView itemText;
        View image;
        View view=convertView;
        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        }

        itemText=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
         itemText.setText(items[position]);

        image=new SampleView(context);
        LinearLayout ln1=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ll1);


        ln1.addView(image,1);
         return view;
    }
    public int getCount() {
           return items.length;
          }

          public Object getItem(int position) {
           return position;
          }

          public long getItemId(int position) {
           return position;
          }
}
```

Comment: can you share the adapter code?

Comment: I have added the code please check and if any doubt plz ask.

Comment: so the problem is that your sampleview is not added? why don't you add it in the xml?

Comment: I told you SampleView is a custom View.How can i add that in a xml? I m drawing a arc in that view and trying to add into listadapter or you can say listview.

Comment: see this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html the final part is about xml

Comment: Now you post the link for how to create customview, is not it? See I created sampleview in separate activity and set like this setContentView(new SampleView).It worked fine.Now i am trying to add into listview it not getting added.

Comment: i still think it would work better if the sampleview was declared inside your listitem.xml I only posted that link to show you how to include custom views in xml layout.

Comment: oh yeah i did not notice that.+1 to you comment.I am going to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
private class ItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    String[] items;
    Context context;
    public ItemsAdapter(Context context,String[] items){
        this.items=items;
        this.context=context;
    }

    public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup Parent){
       ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);


        }
        holder.itemText=(TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.itemText.setText(items[position]);

        holder.image=new SampleView(context);
        LinearLayout ln1=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll1);


        ln1.addView(holder.image,1);
        return convertView;
    }
    public int getCount() {
           return items.length;
          }

          public Object getItem(int position) {
           return position;
          }

          public long getItemId(int position) {
           return position;
          }

     class ViewHolder {
            TextView itemText;
            View image;
     }
}
```

Comment: Didnt work.sorry.Actually i m drawing a circle inside that custom view which is also drawing a canvas.So is there any problem due to canvas?